# How to query pod creation time in Grafana?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am new to Grafana Monitoring and not quite familiar with PromQL query. I wanted to try to retrieve a table has pod names and time created from Kubernetes cluster. How do I need to retrieve the info using PromQL?

For instance, in the table will have

Pod Name nginx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx and creation time HH:MM:SS or any suitable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metric `kube_pod_created` which returns the time in unix timestamp. Multiply the value by 1000 and select date format.

```
kube_pod_created{pod="nginx-xxx"} * 1000
```

More you can find here https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6297.